# Die grammatische Konstruktion von "des Öfteren"

Tags: etymology, capitalization, ellipsis

Den Ausdruck "des öfteren/Öfteren" sieht man nicht selten. Ich werde aber nicht klar darüber, warum hier offenbar der Genitiv verwendet wird.
  Es dürfte sich um eine Ellipse handeln, aber was für ein Wort ist denn dann weggelassen?

Ich habe die Schreibweise sowohl mit Klein- als auch Großschreibung von "öfteren" gesehen. Was ist richtig?

Comment: Ich glaube kaum, dass es sich hier um eine Ellipse handelt. Vor allem da "des Öfteren" häufig durch "oft" ersetzbar ist, würde ich eher vermuten, dass es sich um ein "substantivertes Adverb" handelt.

Comment: @ixolius Ja, das ist mir klar, aber warum steht das Substantiv in Genitiv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zur Schreibung kann ich Antwort geben:

Im Duden von 1989 - also zur Zeit der guten alten Rechtschreibung - war der Ausdruck

> des öfteren

nur in dieser Form vorgesehen.

Die Variante in Großschreibung ist eine Folge der sogenannten Rechtschreibreform der 1990er Jahre, mit der versucht wurde, der Sprachgemeinschaft eine Reihe von neuen Schreibweisen aufzudrängen, weil diese angeblich leichter zu lernen seien als die alten, die sich aus langer Schriftsetzer- und Verlagspraxis entwickelt hatten. Bei dieser Reform folgte man der Idee, dass es leichter sei, jedes Wort, vor dem ein Artikel steht ("der, die, das", hier in der Genitivform "des") einfach unbesehen groß zu schreiben. So wurde auch aus

> im allgemeinen

das heute recht verbreitete "im Allgemeinen", aus

> im wesentlichen

wurde "im Wesentlichen" und

> der zweite

wurde "der Zweite". Wenigstens in Texten von Leuten, die sich an der sogenannten neuen Rechtschreibung orientieren.

Zur eigentlichen Frage: Welche Schreibung ist "richtig"?

In den neueren Duden-Ausgaben wird die Form nunmehr nur mit Großschreibung aufgeführt:

> des Öfteren

Ich würde aber aus Gründen der Tradition und des Schriftbilds (oder man kann es auch gerne Sturheit nennen), die Form mit Kleinschreibung vorziehen.

Man kann auch sagen: Bist du Schüler, und dein Lehrer besteht auf "neuer Rechtschreibung" wirst du zur Schonung deiner Nerven "des Öfteren" schreiben müssen. Bist du ein freier Mensch und legst Wert auf zeitenüberspannende  Schriftkultur, wirst du vielleicht "des öfteren" vorziehen.

**Noch zur grammatischen Form:** Ohne dass dies eine wirkliche Antwort wäre... aber es gibt eine Reihe solcher Ausdrücke, wo Genitiv für eine zeitliche oder räumliche Bestimmungen eingesetzt wird:

> *Des Morgens und des Abends* führte er sein Hündlein spazieren. Dabei erzählte er ihm *des Langen und des Breiten* von den guten alten Zeiten. *Des öfteren* geriet er dabei ins Schwärmen.

---

Referenzwerke:

- Duden, Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 2. Auflage, 1989
- Duden, Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 8. Auflage, 2015 (S. 1290)

Comment: Darüber, ob die alte Rechtschreibung wirklich so gut war, kann man durchaus auch anderer Meinung sein. Ich finde die neue Rechtschreibung viel geradliniger und logischer als die alte. Und 21 Jahre nach ihrer Einführung könnte man sich auch langsam daran gewöhnen und aufhören daran herumzunörgeln. (Das bin ich sonst eher von den Wienern gewöhnt).

Comment: Die Charakterisierung der ehemaligen Rechtschreibung ist sachlich falsch: «die sich aus langer Schriftsetzer- und Verlagspraxis entwickelt hatten». Die Rechtschreibung von 1876/1902 ist nämlich ebenso das Resultat einer kleinen Expertengruppe wie die Rechtschreibung von 1996/2006. Die Eingriffe in die zuvor üblichen Schreibungen waren weit grösser, und zu ihrer Zeit war sie bei den Nörglern mindestens ebenso umstritten, und der Prozess bis zur definitiven Reform dauerte mehr als doppelt so lang.

Comment: @Hubert  Gewöhnen? Nicht nötig. Was sinnvoll ist an neuen Schreibweisen (eigentlich nur die Regelung zu ss/ß) kann man übernehmen (tut man auch). Den meisten Blödsinn haben die Reförmler ja selbst wieder revidiert, entweder ganz oder aber indem sie alte Formen ebenso zulassen wie neue.